# Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find the derivative of an integral with variable lower limit

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$, and define $H$ on $[a,b]$ by $H(x)= \int_x^b f$. Find $H'(x)$.

I use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $\int_a^xf(t)dt=F(x)$, but I am lost, asking for help.

Comment: Can someone guess what is written up there?

Comment: @DonAntonio just change it

Comment: Wow, that's a huge difference, @megan. Good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$H(x)=\int\limits_x^b f(t)dt=-\int\limits_b^x f(t)dt=-F(x)\;\ldots$$

Comment: never mind i got it haha

Comment: wait, but it is on [a,b]. and FTC show should be $\int_a^xf=F(x)$, but here is b. so....

Comment: Who cares, @megan ? The fact is that, as long as we're within $\;[a,b]\;$ , and we're so assuming, and the lower limit is a constant we're cool. If you want you can look it as $$\int\limits_x^b=\int\limits_a^b-\int\limits_a^x$$ ...It's just the same!

Comment: ok you are right Thanks